# Automate image upload on CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, browser-automation

I need to upload images on a website that uses CKEditor. For each image, I click "image" button -> "upload" tab -> "**Choose file**" button -> select file in file-browser -> "Send to server" button -> Wait for upload -> "Ok" button

I am almost able to trigger appropriate "clicks" by entering javascript code in console except for the bolded step, i.e, I am not able to trigger "**Choose file**" button on CKEditor, i.e, I am not able to programmatically click the "Browse" button. Note that once file-browser opens up, (by manual click), I can use  autohotkey to enter address of my file followed by 'enter'. 
Alternatively, I am not able to set the image upload path using javascript (skipping file-open dialog), which is a security risk, but I need to bypass it, at least by using my own addon/extension. 
Please help me trigger the file browser or set image path directly into input.

Here is a demo of CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/demo

I could make following so far.

```
//click image button
document.getElementsByClassName("cke_button__image")[0].click();

// click "upload" tab
document.getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_tab")[2].click();

//Need to either trigger "choose file" dialog box or otherwise assign "C:\temp.png" to input

//Click "send to server" button
document.getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_ui_button")[4].click();

//Need to wait, and then click "OK" button
document.getElementsByClassName("cke_dialog_ui_button")[6].click();
```

More info: I am writing chrome-extension to inject javascript function that could "click()" appropriate buttons. Since I am ready to build extension, there must be a way to bypass security. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the file picker dialog pops up, you can't control it with javascript, and in an input type="file" you can't also set its value because that would be a security risk.

You need to move to an environment with higher permissions in order to fully achieve what you want.

Comment: thank you so much! but what environment should I use then? Also, I am not able to trigger file picker at all! I manually click the "choose file" button and then use autohotkey to type the address of file followed by enter. let me edit my question to make that clear! The "choose file" button is inside iframe, and probably that's why I am unable to trigger it.

Comment: If using autohotkey you're able to type into the file picker dialog then that's OK, it just depends on how you're executing your code and I don't know your full context. Personally I don't use the default file upload of CKEditor because it's too restricted, but you might find easier to use the CKEditor API to target the input because as you say it's in an iframe and I think that doesn't have any name or id that you can use.

Comment: I did use class, but it doesnt work, I used click() on all elements I could see inside iframe, but file-dialog box does not gets triggered!

Comment: also, what "environment" should I use to to directly write the path?

Comment: You can launch the file picker at http://ckeditor.com/demo (once the dialog is open) with CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().getContentElement("Upload", "upload").getInputElement().$.click() then it's up to you how to type in that dialog and press its OK button

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, I tried this line of code when upload tab is visible, but it still did not trigger the file-dialog box, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess that you're testing with Chrome. That code works correctly with Firefox and IE11, but I suppose that Chrome doesn't allow to simulate clicks unless it's in a user generated event.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I tested this in firefox 35 (not working), but works in internet explorer 11. I have no idea about IE extensions and also IE might disable this eventually for "security reasons". Btw, what environment should I use to get higher permissions? Using autohotkey is also messy, as it sometimes does not work!!

Comment: I tested with Firefox 40 and it worked and I doubt that this behaviour has changed recently. Also you shouldn't use an old version because it contains big security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw, what is environment with higher permissions? Also, I tried again in firefox 40, still not working :(

Comment: Higher permissions means something that it isn't executed as javascript in the context of a page. I dont have the required knowledge to advice you about that.